# "Mount" Audio CD with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio, streaming

I want to share music in my local network with UPnP.
The program i use on my Ubuntu 10.10 homeserver takes a path to a folder containing the music and i want to insert an audio cd which should be distributed, but its not possible to simply mount such cds, is it?
What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

Rip the CD to disk in your preferred file format, then share the folder. It doesn't occupy that much, and you get much faster access than an audio-CD, especially with multiple connections.

Comment: Or even with a single connection, since the CD would have to spin up on first access.